# Appcelerator Studio won't work with any version of Node

Tags: installation, appcelerator, appcelerator-studio

folks

Recently updating node on OS prompted me to move from Titanium to Appcelerator Studio since Titanium just stopped working and is no longer supported

After installing Appcelerator Studio, I realized there was an issue with an issue with Node, which had been installed from brew, so I uninstalled it, and reinstalled using npm instead... No glory

Reading up on some former issues, I realized some people had issues with the minimum required node version of 0.12.7, and by downgrading to 0.10.33, were able to get it to work

This was not my case. I have tried with the latest version, with 0.12.7, with 0.10.33 and 0.10.35... neither work and all give the following stack trace...

```
2016-03-06T15:23:50.889Z | TRACE  | TypeError: Incorrect value of args option
    at normalizeSpawnArguments (child_process.js:323:11)
    at exports.spawn (child_process.js:356:38)
    at run (/Users/david/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.3.0.GA/node_modules/node-appc/lib/subprocess.js:47:14)
    at Object.detect (/Users/david/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.3.0.GA/node_modules/node-appc/lib/jdk.js:71:3)
    at Object.async.parallel.jdk (/Users/david/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.3.0.GA/node_modules/titanium-sdk/lib/android.js:71:13)
    at /Users/david/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.3.0.GA/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:524:25
    at /Users/david/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.3.0.GA/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:111:13
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at _each (/Users/david/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.3.0.GA/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:32:24)
    at Object.async.each (/Users/david/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.3.0.GA/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:110:9)
```

It's also noteworthy that merely opening appcelerator studio prompts an update to 0.12.7, which I haven't been able to get around

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Titanium 3.3.0 is almost 2 years old and build for Node.JS 0.8. But Appcelerator Studio is unlikely to work with that NodeJS version since we require 0.12.

To still work with Titanium 3.3.0 you probably need Titanium CLI 3.3.0 (`sudo npm i -g titanium@3.3.0`) and NodeJS 0.8.

Comment: That stack trace is from Appcelerator Studio. I didn't even notice the 3.3.0 GA... I guess there's a conflict with the pre existing Titanium Studio. Is there a recommended way to uninstall Titanium?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with conflict with pre existing Ti Studio, but as I said your best guess to compile with such an old SDK is to use the Titanium CLI and NodeJS version I suggested. You don't need to uninstall a previous version of the Titanium CLI as it will just be replaced.

Comment: You may refer this link: https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Titanium+Compatibility+Matrix#TitaniumCompatibilityMatrix-Node.js